# kde opensuse insufficient permission to use Internet?

Tags: internet-connection, kde, opensuse

I suddenly found myself having the problem that I can't use Internet services.
I can't use `ssh`, `ping` or a web browser.
As super user however I can `ping`, no `ssh` as far as I can tell.
I thought it could be permissions as I can `ping` from root.
But this seems to be all I can do from root.

1. My `/var/log/xorg.0.log` has:

   > (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modsetting
   >   (WW) ditto for fbdev

   nothing which I understand or believe should be behind the error
2. The file `boot.log` show that is all OK.
3. Also have a log named: `wpa_suppliant.log`  which show authentication (all ok) for my wireless connection:

   > wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTEF - connection to blah completed [id=0 id_str=]
4. `zypper search foo`  give me:

   > Error code: connection failed

I don't know how to go about from here tracing the error.
I am sorry if the information is sparse, but I'm using my phone to type.

Comment: ifconfig -a Show RX and TX packets being delivered (I think). There is a loopback which I am not sure wh a t it does but it feels like it's been there before as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out while at work I had gotten **nameservers** set from work. so in `/etc/resolve.conf` nameservers (which aren't the same as I have at home) were set. Which makes perfect sense now.. I could kind of `ping 8.8.8.8` as `root` but nothing else, I should have seen it earlier since when I used ssh, I never tried doing so on the ip-address.

However to resolve this I had to do a manual `netconfig update -f` to make it work. I guess I may well run into this problem tomorrow as well, or perhaps not? but I guess if that is the case I should be able to edit `/etc/resolve.conf` and add my own dns augmented to the once I get from work. So hopefully I will experience the problem tomorrow as well.